# How can I make nautilus-gsku work in 11.10?

Tags: nautilus, gksu

I have installed `nautilus-gksu` on 11.10, but it isn't working. How can I make the "Open as administrator" option appear in the context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug (link?) and there [is a workaround](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861721) for it:

- Copy the old extension into the Nautilus 3 extensions folder with the following command:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/libnautilus-gksu.so /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/
```

- Then restart Nautilus:

  - From the command line with

    ```
    killall nautilus
    ```
  - or, log out and log back in